# HowTo Remove brackets in an Angular object

Tags: angular, rest, http, drupal

for a readable patch method, my Drupal site needs this:

```
{
  "_links":
  {"type":{"href":"http://drupal.dd:8083/rest/type/node/task"}},
  "nid":{"":5},
  "title":{"value":"Change"},
  "body":{"":"i dont know why?"}
}
```

What I have done so far is this:

```
{
  "_links":
  [{"type":{"href":"http://drupal.dd:8083/rest/type/node/task"}}],
  "nid":[{"":5}],
  "title":[{"value":"Change"}],
  "body":[{"":"i dont know why?"}]
}
```

It have brackets everywhere...

In my angular app i am getting all the data from a form, and sending to this function to create the data for the webservice:

```
   save(name: string, body:string): void {
  let task: any = {
      _links: [],
      nid: [],
      title: [],
      body: []     
   };
   const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
   task.nid.push({"": id});
   task._links.push({type: {"href": "http://drupal.dd:8083/rest/type/node/task"} });
   task.title.push({value: name});
   task.body.push({ "": body});
   console.log(JSON.stringify(task));

   }
```

So my question is, **How to remove the brackets from the object?**

Comment: Why initialize each property as an array and `.push` if you do not want an array? You can simply do `let tasks: any = {_links: null}; tasks._links = {type: ...};`

Comment: @LLai how do I fill them? I mean, do I use `task.nid.push` ? or what? sorry for the question is just starting

Comment: `.push()` is an array operator. It will push a value to an array. For example `let arr = []; arr.push(1); // arr = [1];` When dealing with objects you can set the property by `object.propName`. so in your case `task._links = yourValue;` You can also set the property when you initialize the object `let task = {_links: yourValue};` I would suggest reading up on [Objects and Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Listo, perfecto!

Comment: @LLai hey!  Hi! you was right with your solution! .. can you upvote my question, please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Llai was right, i dont need an array:

```
  let task: any = {
      _links: null,
      nid: null,
      title: null,
      body: null     
   };
   const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
   task.nid = {"": id};
   task._links = {type: {"href": "http://drupal.dd:8083/rest/type/node/task"} };
   task.title = {value: name};
   task.body = { "": body};
```